# Datatable sorting not working properly after destroyed the table and recreate

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I using Jquery to clear the table tbody and reinsert in via ajax call. after the data is showed, but the sorting function is not working properly. here is my codes..

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content table-hover" style="table-layout:fixed;" id="datatable1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="agtBody">
        <?php 
        foreach($results as $result) :
        ?>
            <tr>
                <?php if(isset($game_name['gpname'])){?>
                    <td><?=$game_name['gpname']?></td>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    <td><?=$result['gpid']?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($result['betAmt'])?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($result['payout'])?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($result['winLoss'])?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($result['validbetamount'])?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id ="agtFoot">
        <tr style="background-color:#FFEEDD;">
            <td>Total</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($totalbetAmt)?></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($totalpayout)?></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($totalwinLoss)?></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><?=Helper::money($totalvalidbetamount)?></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search_agtdetail(agentcode) {
        if($("#agt_StartTime").val() == "" || $("#agt_EndTime").val() == "") {
            alert("<?php echo 'Not Valid' ?>"); 
        } else {
            $("#agtBody").empty();
            $("#agtFoot").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/report/agentBoxAjax",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    start_date: $("#agt_StartTime").val(),
                    end_date: $("#agt_EndTime").val(),
                    agent_code : agentcode,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#datatable1').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    $('#agtBody').html(data.html);
                    $('#agtFoot').html(data.html_foot);
                    $('#datatable1').css('width', '');
                    $('#datatable1').dataTable({
                        'bPaginate':false,
                        'bSort': true,
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datatable1').dataTable({
            'bPaginate':false,
            'bSort': true,
        });
    });

</script>
```

Can someone help me? The sorting is not working properly.. 
Its look like using the old data for sorting it. 
i had less experience on jquery, someone please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: jQuery datatable need to refresh and redraw using its API methods and not replacing the html directly. You need to provide data in JSON format, see this for more detail https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Bhushan Kawadkar comment you need to use the API method for this.Also you should be using the ajax methods for your datatable.

For example, lets say that i get the server side data from a script called data.php, i would just call it like this:

```
$('#datatable1').dataTable({
    'bPaginate':false,
    'bSort': true,
    "ajax": {
         "url": "data.php",
         "type": "GET"
    }
});
```

the post.php needs to return the data in json format like this (using car as example):

```
{
    "data":[
         [
             "Ford",
             "Fiesta",
             "2015"
         ],
    ]
}
```

in your success section in the ajax call instead of destroying the table just use:

```
$('#datatable1').ajax.reload()
```

Here's a snippet just in case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt',
  });
  
   $("#reload_table").on("click",function(){
        console.log("reloading data");
        table.ajax.reload();
   });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<html>

<body>
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</body>

<input id="reload_table" type="button" value="RELOAD TABLE">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</html>
```